# Is it possible to attach my window to a window of another application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

On Windows we can find the window handle of running process and attach our window onto it as a child window, so the two different processes look like the same one.

I wonder if there is a similar way to implement this requirement in cocoa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using code injection. Have a look at [mach inject framework](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_inject) and [PorcShark Finder](http://oin.name/porcsharkfinder/).

[image]

Or
Find position of another window using `CGWindow` methods and display your window over it.
Have a look at [Son of Grab](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project.

> Son of Grab shows how to use the new CGWindow API to get images of arbitrary sets
>   of windows, including images of the current contents of the screen.